# Passing the name of a function as the eventMouseover callback

Tags: fullcalendar

I'm trying to pass the actual name of a function rather than an anonymous function to my FullCalendar initialization like so:

```
$('#gcally_calendar').fullCalendar({
    "eventSources":    
        [...],
    "eventMouseover":"fc_hover_in"
});
```

I'm getting a console error when I do this, however: `Uncaught TypeError: Array.prototype.slice.call is not a function`.

Any thoughts on this?

For thoroughness, this is the function:

```
function fc_hover_in(calEvent, jsEvent, view) {
var tooltip = '<div class="tooltipevent" style="width:100px;height:100px;background:#ccc;position:absolute;z-index:10001;">' + calEvent.title + '</div>';
jQuery("body").append(tooltip);
jQuery(this).mouseover(function(e) {
    $(this).css('z-index', 10000);
    $('.tooltipevent').fadeIn('500');
    $('.tooltipevent').fadeTo('10', 1.9);
}).mousemove(function(e) {
    $('.tooltipevent').css('top', e.pageY + 10);
    $('.tooltipevent').css('left', e.pageX + 20);
});
}
```

But it's not even being called at this point.

Comment: As pointed in the answer from A1rpun here under, you probably want to use not the name of the function, but a pointer to that function, so you need to remove the quotes around it as else you're just passing a string...

Answer (score 0):

You should remove the quotes to pass the function as a reference.
This:

```
"eventMouseover":"fc_hover_in"
```

Becomes this:

```
"eventMouseover": fc_hover_in
```